# DateTime.ParseExact string format exception

Tags: c#, string, datetime, parsing

I am trying to convert a string into datetime with the following C# code,

```
DateTime dTo = DateTime.ParseExact(dateTo, "mm/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

eachtime I pass dateTo as 1/1/2010 it fails, instead it needs the string to be 01/01/2010.

What string format should I use to support both 01/01/2010 and 1/1/2010?

Comment: Not an exact dup, but this covers much the same territory: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368636/why-cant-datetime-parseexact-parse-9-1-2009-using-m-d-yyyy

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Using the following date format expression will allow you to use either single or double digit day and month elements.

```
"M/d/yyyy"
```

Note that the capital `M` is significant - a lower case `m` is the placeholder for minutes.

You will find more information related to date format strings [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97x6twsz.aspx).

You can use the following Powershell command to test them.

```
[DateTime]::ParseExact('01/01/2010', 'M/d/yyyy', $null)
```

Comment: will this not let you have leading zeros though?

Comment: I did not know this, green-mushroom for you sir!

Answer (score 3):

Capital M is month, little m is mins i think.

But to the point of the question, use Parse. ParseExact implies you know the exact format of the input.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this format: `MM/dd/yyyy`, but I think there's no single format string that could support both inputs. You could test if the length of your `dateTo` string is less than 10 characters use `M/d/yyyy`, otherwise `MM/dd/yyyy`.