# Converting String to DateTime results in error

Tags: c#, datetime

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [DateTime.ParseExact string format exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000580/datetime-parseexact-string-format-exception)

`FormatException` was found !

I tried to convert a string to `DateTime`.

```
string dateString1 = "5/22/1985 12:00:00 AM";

DateTime myDate = 
    DateTime.ParseExact(dateString1, 
                        "mm-dd-yyyy",
                        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

It gives me an error, but when I try to convert a string in this format

```
string dateString2 = "10-10-2000";
```

This second string is working just fine but the `dateString1` does not work!

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000580/datetime-parseexact-string-format-exception

Comment: "mm" in `DateTime` format strings means **minutes**, not months.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString1, "M/d/yyyy h:m:s tt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 6):

Your code answers your question. You're using `ParseExact`, which was given a format that won't accept your first string.

From the MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx):

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its DateTime equivalent using the specified format and culture-specific format information. The format of the string representation must match the specified format exactly.

Answer (score 0):

You're specifically making your code parse the date exactly according to the format "mm-dd-yyyy", so of course only a date with that format will work. If you use DateTime.Parse instead, both examples will work.

Comment: Thanks ! I realize that now , thanks for the tips. It is the first time I use DateTime, I'm stil learning :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Parse instead of ParseExact:

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.Parse(dateString1);
```

This should correctly parse either of your two examples.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1k1skd40.aspx

Comment: its not working DateTime myDate = DateTime.Parse("5/22/1985 12:00:00 AM")