# DateTime.ParseExact raises FormatException

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

The code:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("2/2/2002", "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

is raising `System.FormatException`.

I'll really appreciate if anybody could tell me  what am I doing wrong.

Comment: DateTime.ParseExact("02/02/2002", "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)

Comment: I see dd/MM and I see 2/2

Comment: Duplicate: [DateTime.ParseExact string format exception](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000580/)

Answer (score 8):

it should be `d/M/yyyy`

```
DateTime.ParseExact("2/2/2002", "d/M/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

the reason of exception  is that it converts two places for `dd` but the string found is `2/`.