# Why can’t DateTime.ParseExact() parse the AM/PM in “4/4/2010 4:20:00 PM” using “M'/'d'/'yyyy H':'mm':'ss' 'tt”

Tags: c#, datetime, parsing

I'm using c#, and if I do

```
DateTime.ParseExact("4/4/2010 4:20:00 PM", "M'/'d'/'yyyy H':'mm':'ss' 'tt", null)
```

The return value is always 4:20 AM -- what am I doing wrong with using tt?

Thanks!

Comment: Several right answers... since I can only choose one right answer, I assume I should pick the first one to be submitted?

Answer (score 77, accepted):

Make the hour format (`H`) lowercase like this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact(
            "4/4/2010 4:20:00 PM", 
            "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss tt", 
            CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Uppercase "H" indicates 24-hour time and lowercase "h" indicates 12-hour time and will respect the AM/PM in the candidate string.

*Side note:* It is best to provide an instance of `IFormatProvider` to methods like this (even if it's just `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`).  It's one of those things that doesn't really matter until you hit problems with it so it can be good to be in the habit of specifying culture information.

Comment: Thanks for the side note! I discussed this in another one of my  questions:
@Jimmy: It depends on the intent. In this case, / is used as an exact slash and not as a culture-sensitive separator (even when the culture is InvariantCulture), so the option that better expresses your intent is the one with quoted slashes (the one you picked) - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368636/why-cant-datetime-parseexact-parse-9-1-2009-using-m-d-yyyy . At the time I agreed with his conclusion (i.e., use '/' and null for the culture, rather than use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture). What do you think?

Comment: Great! It was the CultureInfo.InvariantCulture missing in my case, casue I had a lowercase 'h' and it still didn't parse!

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact("4/4/2010 4:20:00 PM", "M'/'d'/'yyyy h':'mm':'ss tt", null));
```

This outputs:

```
 4/4/2010 4:20:00 PM
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a lowercase "h" for the hour argument in the format string.  The uppercase "H" represents 24-hour time, so "4" is recognized as 4 AM (since "16" would be 4 PM).

```
DateTime.ParseExact("4/4/2010 4:20:00 PM", "M/d/yyyy h:mm:ss:tt", null)
```