# How to allow datetime field to accept AM and PM

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime, informix

I have a field in my database of type `DateTime` but i configure it to be just a time like that `10:00` .

Now  i wanna to accept the time in the format like that :

`10:00 AM` or `10:00 PM` ..

Comment: I try to insert time like `10:00 AM` in a field of type Datetime .informix database

Comment: Why not use 24 hour notation instead? `10:00` and `22:00`?

Comment: the user prefer the previous notation

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596969/why-cant-datetime-parseexact-parse-the-am-pm-in-4-4-2010-42000-pm-using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Get the all `DateTime` in your query
2. Use [IF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717.aspx) for your field
3. Use syntax like

   If (Hours of Datetime > 12) 
   Then 
   Hours of Datetime - 12 + "PM"

I agree this is little bir confused but this is the structure you should follow.