# Calculating total numbersof hours for attendance

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, vb.net

Am Working on Attendance system in asp.net, I have two labels and Textboxes:

1. Textbox1 for Time entry.
2. Textbox2 for leave entry.

Both are inputted by user in terms for example: Entry time is: (7:50 AM) and the Leave time is: (6:15 PM).
Now I want to calculate the total numbers of hours for the inputted entries.
keeping in mind in the day he/she has 30 minutes break. So how to do that?

Comment: It would depend on the database engine you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Convert `TextBox1.Text` to `System.DateTime entry`
2. Convert `TextBox2.Text` to `System.DateTime leave`
3. Calculate `Timespan t = leave - entry - Timespan.FromMinutes(30)`
4. Get `t.TotalHours()`

For converting time string into `DateTime` use `DateTime.ParseExact` ( [Why can’t DateTime.ParseExact() parse the AM/PM in “4/4/2010 4:20:00 PM” using “M'/'d'/'yyyy H':'mm':'ss' 'tt”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596969/why-cant-datetime-parseexact-parse-the-am-pm-in-4-4-2010-42000-pm-using) )

```
    var ci = new CultureInfo("en-US");

    DateTime entry = DateTime.ParseExact("7:50 AM", "h:mm tt", ci);
    DateTime leave = DateTime.ParseExact("6:15 PM", "h:mm tt", ci);

    TimeSpan t = leave - entry - TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);

    var totalTime = string.Format("{0:D2}h:{1:D2}m", t.Hours, t.Minutes);
```

Comment: The question says total hours.

Comment: @DanBracuk I don't understand, are you proposing that I should use `t.Hours()` instead?

Comment: Just to add some formatting, you could use `var totalTime = string.Format("{0:D2}h:{1:D2}m", t.Hours, t.Minutes);` to get hours and mins.

Comment: @NemanjaBoric, I think "total hours for the inputted entries" means a database query to get previously entered values as well.  Of course, the question does not explicitly state that.