# Insert datetime2 into database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime2

I am using `datetime2` as the datatype for `checkIn` and `checkOut`. Previously I can add into database with this code.

```
//value for checkIn = 12/25/2015 2:00:00 PM
checkIn = DateTime.ParseExact(Session["checkInDate"].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).AddHours(14);

//value for checkOut = 12/26/2015 12:00:00 PM
checkOut = DateTime.ParseExact(Session["checkOutDate"].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).AddHours(12);

strInsert = "INSERT INTO Reservation ( checkInDate, checkOutDate) VALUES (@checkInDate, @checkOutDate)";

cmdInsert = new SqlCommand(strInsert, conn);
cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@checkInDate", checkIn);
cmdInsert.Parameters.AddWithValue("@checkOutDate", checkOut);
```

But now it doesn't work and I am getting this error;

> "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string".

I think the error is caused by the check in value which contain the "PM" and "AM", but it is weird because previously I am able to add this into the database.

Does anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: Are you really sure your both column is `datetime2`? In such a case, `AddWithValue` _might_ generate a problem maybe. Have you ever tried it with `Add` and specify your parameter type?

Comment: Would you post the values from your dates prior to the exception?

Comment: Tagged MySQL but datetime2 is SQL Server?

Comment: @AlexK. And used `SqlCommand` :)

Comment: Try w/ `cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("@checkInDate", SqlDbType.DateTime2).value = checkIn;`

Comment: The error message suggests that `.AddWithValue` is going wrong and converting your datetimes to strings. Which may mean that your `DateTime.ParseExact` has gone wrong. So try giving it a more accurate format to use in parsing: [Why can’t DateTime.ParseExact() parse the AM/PM in “4/4/2010 4:20:00 PM” using “M'/'d'/'yyyy H':'mm':'ss' 'tt”](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2596991/1115360).

Comment: As a best practice, don't use `AddWithValue` as much as you can. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you want to discard the time part of `checkInDate`. Using `ParseExact` to do that is not really the correct way. Instead you can use the `.Date` property of a DateTime and then add on the hours.

Also, to avoid the hassles which `.AddWithValue` can give, simply use `.Add`, so...

```
string s = "12/25/2015 2:00:00 PM";
DateTime checkIn = DateTime.Parse(s, CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US")).Date.AddHours(14);
// ....
string strInsert = "INSERT INTO Reservation (checkInDate, checkOutDate) VALUES (@checkInDate, @checkOutDate)";

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmdInsert = new SqlCommand(strInsert, conn))
    {
        cmdInsert.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@checkInDate", SqlDbType.DateTime2).Value = checkIn);
        // ....
    }
}
```

Note that you can store a DateTime in a Session value, there is no need to store it as a string.

I notice that you quote the checkin date in USA date format (MM/dd/yyyy), but your format in `.ParseExact` is "dd/MM/yyyy". This may also be a source of trouble.