# C# SqlDataAdapter DateTime Format datatable invalid json \Date()

Tags: c#, asp.net

[Solved] So it was a stupid issue and i figured it by tracking the variable changes throughout the call stack and fixed it as follows: 
(Reason and solution mentioned in step 5)

ref: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/

1- Database column:

[image]

2- Database stored procedure:
[image]

3- C# call that stored procedure:
[image]

4- C# parse the date (it is returned as a string )
[image]

5- Casting that string to datetime (My issue started here, I should not convert the datetime-string back to a datetime object when i need to pass it to a Json() to use it for DataTable plugin for example. Only Razor can handle DateTime objects ..., So the solution was to just skip this step, if you are using a model-model or a view-model, you need to include a string property to store the string version of the datetime or just use another currently-not-in-use property, I used IBAN property to store the datetime-string-version instated of creating a new model or modifying the domain model i was using):
[image]

Thanks

Comment: What's the column type in the database?

Comment: If you're using your database properly, this is a non-issue. The column in the database will already be an SQL `DateTime` type, and ADO.Net will automatically give you a .Net `DateTime` type in the results. Anytime you're dealing with converting string values to or from dates with SQL, you're already doing something _**very**_ wrong.

Comment: Why is the value not stored as `DateTime` in the database?

Comment: So your value is stored as a `DateTime` in the database, and your stored procedure converts it to a string? **Don't do that**.

Comment: As a general rule: You should leave values as the correct type until the last possible moment (display to the user). Otherwise you end up on Stack Overflow asking questions like this one.

Answer (score 0):

On [server side](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles),

```sql
convert(datetime, 'Dec 30 2006 12:38AM', 109)
```

On [client side](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2596969/11683),

```cs
DateTime.ParseExact("Dec 30 2006 12:38AM", "MMM dd yyyy h:mmtt", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Comment: It needs another h: "MMM dd yyyy h:mmtt"
Thanks

Comment: @AdelMourad It may have another, `h`, but it does not need it. With `h`, it will handle both `12:38AM` and `2:38AM`. With `hh`, it will fail on `2:38AM`.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use DateTime.Parse()?

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dateString = "Dec 30 2006 12:38AM";
            var date = DateTime.Parse(dateString);
            Console.WriteLine(date);
            // results is 30/12/2006 00:38:00 (according to my DateTime format settings)
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```