# Error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

I've been trying to convert a string to DateTime but an error occurred. This is the code that gave the error:

```
public static string recorded = "12/07/2019 02:37:00 PM";
DateTime check = DateTime.ParseExact(recorded, "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

As far as I'm concerned, the format I'm using matches the string perfectly (every number has 2 digits/letters, they have the same symbols used). I thought that maybe I was just using the wrong format so I tried using 2 formats from [here](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/date-and-time-format-in-c-sharp-programming1).Specifically, `"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm tt"` and `"MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss"`. Only the latter worked so I'm thinking that the problem lies in the AM/PM but the problem is that I need it, so I can't use the latter format. I even tried using lowercase `pm` and `Pm` but both didn't work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2596969/why-can-t-datetime-parseexact-parse-the-am-pm-in-4-4-2010-42000-pm-using   use `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The format string `HH` refers to 24-hour format and cannot be used in conjunction with `tt`. Use `hh` instead. This:

```
DateTime check = DateTime.ParseExact(recorded, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

works just fine.

Comment: It's not working in the dotnetfiddle, maybe it was because of the website I'm using?

Comment: [Format string docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)

Answer (score 1):

You need lower case hh: `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss tt`.