# C# DateTime.ParseExact

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

I have a tab delimited file which is being parsed and then inserted into a database. When I run into the date column, I have trouble parsing it.

The code I have is:

```
var insert = DateTime.ParseExact(line[i], "d/M/yyyy h:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

The string in `line[i]` is in the formats: `7/7/2011 10:48` , `10/20/2011 6:27`

The exception I get says

> The DateTime represented by the string is not supported in calendar
>   System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar.

Comment: This works for me, without change for the date string provided.

Comment: It's work for me, Maybe a string in line list has incorrect format.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

Your format string is wrong. Change it to

```
insert = DateTime.ParseExact(line[i], "M/d/yyyy hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: don't you mean `M/d/yyyy` or `d/M/yyyy` He doesn't have any leading zeros on his example

Comment: @Sign: You're right! I've changed my answer. Thanks for mentioning that.

Comment: wow I can't believe I missed that. Turns out the date was in M/d/yyyy instead of d/M/yyyy. I didn't notice because the first few dates were in early days of the month.

Comment: @Jonathan: I only found that, because you had a date like "10/20/2011" in your first version of your question. Later you changed that to "7/7/2011 10:48". ;-)

Comment: Oh LOL, I changed it to show that the format didn't have leading zeros. I didn't even notice the date I used first.

Answer (score 4):

That's because you have the Date in American format in `line[i]` and UK format in the `FormatString`.

```
11/20/2011
M / d/yyyy
```

I'm guessing you might need to change the FormatString to:

```
"M/d/yyyy h:mm"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's probably the same problem with cultures as presented in this related SO-thread: [Why can't DateTime.ParseExact() parse "9/1/2009" using "M/d/yyyy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368636/why-cant-datetime-parseexact-parse-9-1-2009-using-m-d-yyyy)

You already specified the culture, so try escaping the slashes.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
var  insert = DateTime.ParseExact(line[i], "M/d/yyyy h:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```