# Sql server not Accepting Date from text box

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime

I am not able to insert date from text box which is in DD/MM/YYYY format.
I am using Visual Studio 2008 on Windows 7.

my language and regional settings are "ENGLISH(United Kingdom)", and my system is showing today's date like 12/12/2013. The same date i have get in text box via form On load event.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   textBox1.Text = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
}
```

which results into 12/12/2013.

I have placed one button to store date in Table "Table1" which contain only one field Date and its data type is DATETIME. The one click event contains following lines.

```
SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection();
c.ConnectionString ="Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename='D:\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2008\\Projects\\test\\test\\Database1.mdf';Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True";
c.Open();
DateTime d;
d = Convert.ToDateTime(textBox1.Text);
string q = "insert into table1 values('" + d + "')";
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, c);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
MessageBox.Show("record inserted");
```

Whenever i edit date Say today is 12/12/2013(DD/MM/YYYY) and i typed 13/12/2013 , it shows the error Sql exception was unhandeled.

The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.
The statement has been terminated.

and when i type 12/13/2013 (MM/DD/YYYY)

it shows String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Any Suggestion Friends..???

Comment: Try to format the value into YYYY/MM/DD. your region might be in different date format..

Comment: I want DD/MM/YYYY format only.

Comment: using SqlParameter for DateTime type, will do the conversion automatically. Also whenever You convert a string To DateTime like Convert.ToDateTime(textBox1.Text), Always specify format. Similarly in case of Parsing and DateTimeObj.ToString(). Other wise the code will run on some machine and will break on another machine.

Comment: @ priyank Thnks A lot

Answer (score 3):

You should use proper parameters instead of concatanating strings:

```
    string q = "insert into table1 values (@dateparam)";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(q, c);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dataparam", d);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

This will help you with type conversion as well as mitigating SQL injection.

Comment: Sir I am not aware about this format. Will you please show me exactly what i should do or send me link of Simple insert select queries. i will b greatfull

Comment: Read more about SqlParameter class and how it's used. There's lots information on that topic.

Comment: @Flanker [here is the MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) that gives a overview of Parameters

Comment: Its working sir......... Thanks @Szymon. i have learnt a new way to deal with Sql Commands.

Answer (score 0):

use this

```
d=DateTime.ParseExact(text, "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[C# DateTime.ParseExact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401605/c-sharp-datetime-parseexact)

[Parse string to DateTime in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5366285/parse-string-to-datetime-in-c-sharp)

Hope this helps

Comment: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Comment: my string was 13/12/2013

Comment: ok, try using it with a harcoded string like DateTime.ParseExact("04/30/2013 23:00", "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) and see weather it works or not.

Comment: The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value.

Comment: d = DateTime.ParseExact("12/15/2013 23:00","MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm" ,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) ;

Comment: Change the date to "15/12/2013 23:00" and the format to "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm"

Answer (score -1):

Your code:

```
d = Convert.ToDateTime(textBox1.Text);
```

will make d as System.DateTime data type. If you want the format as mm/dd/yyyy - you will have to convert it back to string with the format type

for ex:

```
string q = "insert into table1 values('" + d.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy") + "')";
```

In my opinion - you don't have to convert your text box to date time especially if your sql data type is date time. If you do that for validation - then you should validate the format of text in text box.

Comment: it is working but in a different way it accepts 22/12/2013 (DD/MM/YYYY) insted of MM/DD/YYYY);

Comment: Dates should be passed to SQL server as dates, not string.

Answer (score -1):

Simply change your code,

`Convert.ToDateTime(textbox.text, CultureInfo.InvarientCulture);`

or add this in your 'site.Master.cs' page load event.

// to override the datetime format to "dd-MM-yyyy"(in Site Master)

```
            CultureInfo cl = (CultureInfo)CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Clone();
            cl.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "dd-MM-yyyy";
            cl.DateTimeFormat.LongTimePattern = "";
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cl;
```

now you can use your code like this..

`Convert.ToDateTime(textbox.text, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);`
Now if you publish your code in any local server it will over ride the date format to 'dd-MM-yyyy'.

Comment: This is a SQL Server exception, it's not a result of conversion in the code.