# c#: DateTime.Parse() -- Unrecognized datetime-string

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-parsing

So I got this datetime-string which I get from an external API, `"2014-08-28T11:00:00:000-0400"`.

But I am unable to parse it into a normal DateTime object in C#, I know that last part of the string has something to do with timezone offsets or something, but I am at a loss as to what to do in order for it to parse.

**What I've tried so far:**

```
DateTime.Parse("2019-11-13T05:20:14:311-0700")
DateTime.Parse("2019-11-13T05:20:14:311-0700", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-GB"))
DateTime.Parse("2019-11-13T05:20:14:311-0700", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"))
DateTimeOffset.Parse("2019-11-13T05:20:14:311-0700")
```

A whole other bunch of stuff where I've passed in various format strings like `"yyyy-MM-dd:HH:mm:ss"` but that doesn't do any good either

Please, if someone out there can help me, you'll get a virtual cookie!

Comment: Please show us what you have done so far.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [C# string to DateTime with timezone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10293362/c-sharp-string-to-datetime-with-timezone)

Comment: `DateTime.ParseExact` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8401605 - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact

Comment: I've updated the post with what i've tried so far

Comment: @MaheshWaghmare that doesn't do me any good either, since my datetime string does't look like: 2012-04-20T10:10:00+0200 notice the extra "000" that I have before "0400"

Comment: As per @Jamiec comment. I have checked and it is working. :-  `DateTimeOffset result = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact("2014-08-28T11:00:00:000-0400", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:fffzzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);`

Answer (score 2):

The format string you want to use is either

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:fffzzz
```

or

```
yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss:fffK
```

More information for `zzz` can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#zzzSpecifier) or for `K` [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#KSpecifier)

You can use the above format string with either `DateTime.ParseExact` or `DateTimeOffset.ParseExact` depending on what you're trying to achieve.

Live example: https://rextester.com/DTNT63275