# Convert MM/dd/YYYY string date to datetime

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, datetime, datetime-format

I have a simple string date as: `"11/28/2022"`

And I try to convert to DateTime as:

```
 var currentStartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(
                model.StartDate,
                "dd/MM/yyyy",
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
            );
```

but it throw:

> System.FormatException: The DateTime represented by the string
> '11/28/2022' is not supported in calendar
> 'System.Globalization.GregorianCalendar'.

Or

```
var currentStartDate = DateTime.Parse(model.StartDate);
```

But it is throwing an error two, how can I convert the date to DateTime?

Comment: Look at the actual numbers in that string and tell me what the 28th month of the year is. You even got the format right in the title.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8401633

Comment: @jmcilhinney - It was close in the title. The OP had `MM/dd/YYYY`, but should have been `MM/dd/yyyy`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

problem is that you are using day in place of the month and vice versa. so you have to correct it.

```
 var currentStartDate = DateTime.ParseExact(
                model.StartDate,
                "MM/dd/yyyy",
                CultureInfo.InvariantCulture
            );
```

And for your error, there is no month as such which is 28.