# DateTime.ParseExact FormatException

Tags: .net, datetime, formatexception

Why does the following code generate a FormatException?

```
DateTime.ParseExact("03/01/2012", "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

[image: DateTime.ParseExact]

Perhaps it has something to do with the fact that the code is running under IIS 7.5 Express as a part of an MVC3 site execution logic?

Comment: I ran it in LinqPad and had no problems.

Comment: Try specifying the Invariant Culture if you're going to provide a defined conversion pattern, or providing a pattern more consistent with the culture of the running thread.

Comment: I have added a proof-image of my case =)

Comment: I know it works with InvariantCulture. I was wondering why this particular case was throwing an exception.

Comment: InvariantCulture provides a default date format, which in this case matches the date string you have provided. What is the culture setting of the computer you're running this code on? Its date format apparently isn't the same as the string you provided in the statement. The null format provider value in your statement is making .NET use the computer's date format (culture info) as a default.

Comment: Thank you for explanations. The techical implication must be that slashes are culture sensetive, as Darjan mentioned. Other then that, I can see that I am providing enough info to the CLR object to know what to assign to Day, Month and Year properties on a resultant datetime object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to include CultureInfo, for example:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("03/01/2012", "dd/MM/yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Slashes in format string are culture sensitive and if you don't pass in CultureInfo, current culture is used. You can also use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` and it will work. [Jon Skeet provides some detailed explanation here.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1368681/127027)

Comment: The original method call depended on `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator` which might be `"/"`, `"-"`, `"."`, and so on. If you want to use a literal slash, and you don't want to use the `InvariantCulture`, escape the slash, as in `DateTime.ParseExact("03/01/2012", @"dd\/MM\/yyyy", null);`.

Answer (score 4):

depends on your culture, to take that out of the equation....

```
DateTime.ParseExact("03/01/2012", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 3):

According to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx), a `FormatException` is thrown, given one of these conditions:

```
public static DateTime ParseExact(
    string s,
    string format,
    IFormatProvider provider
)
```

- s or format is an empty string.
- s does not contain a date and time that corresponds to the pattern specified in format.
- The hour component and the AM/PM designator in s do not agree.

If you pass in a null `IFormatProvider`, I *think* it defaults to the current thread's culture. I'd have to look at this in Reflector. Is there any reason you wanted to pass in `null`?

**UPDATE:**

I looked at it in .NET Reflector and it defaults to the current thread's `DateTimeFormatInfo`. I don't know if I'm allowed to post the code here.