# convert string to datetime according to Culture

Tags: c#

does any one know how to convert string into date according to user's culture

i am using this code

```
DateTime.Parse("2-7-1997", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

it works fine since my culture is set to us

but if i pass

```
DateTime.Parse("23-7-1997", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

it throws Format exception

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Is there any thing which converts string into date according to user culture

Comment: What defines "to user's culture" ?? Is this a windows app, a web app ???

Comment: windows app, user cuture means Culture setting like for date currency etc

Comment: Refer this link 


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368636/why-cant-datetime-parseexact-parse-9-1-2009-using-m-d-yyyy

Comment: Your question is bit confusing, do you want to parse a string and output as in current culture ?

Comment: Well, if it's a windows app, you should be able to just convert the datetime, the user's culture/regional settings should ensure that you're converting the string to a date. On my computer your app would convert 23/7/2012 correctly, because I've selected Danish for my regional settings.

Comment: @LajjaThaker the link work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// convert it to a datetime
// "d" is the required format
var date = DateTime.ParseExact("7/23/1997", "d", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

// now you can output the date in the user's culture
var localizedDateString = date.ToString("d");
```