# strange FormatException with DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime

i have a strange behaviour when using the DateTime.ParseExact()

Works fine

```
DateTime.ParseExact("130314111405.000", "ddMMyyhhmmss.fff", null);
```

Format Exception

```
DateTime.ParseExact("130314130001.000", "ddMMyyhhmmss.fff", null);
```

Thanks for any helpful thoughts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `hour` part is 24 hours format. You need `HH` not `hh` which is for 12 hours format.

```
DateTime.ParseExact("130314130001.000", "ddMMyyHHmmss.fff", null); 
                                             //^^^Here
```

Hour `13` can't be parsed with `hh` which supports hours from 0-12.

I am not sure why you are passing `null` for `IFormatProvider`, you should *(see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1368681/961113))* use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` like:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("130314130001.000", "ddMMyyHHmmss.fff", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 2):

**Problem :** You are trying to parse the Hours value which is `13` using small `hh` , which is not supported by small `hh` because From MSDN: [`hh Custom Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The hour, using a 12-hour clock from **01** to **12**.

So  You need to use `HH` instead of `hh` from MSDN [`HH Custom Format`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> The hour, using a 24-hour clock from **00** to **23**.

Try This:

```
 DateTime.ParseExact("130314130001.000", "ddMMyyHHmmss.fff", null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `DateTime.ParseExact("130314130001.000", "ddMMyyHHmmss.fff", null);`

hh is only for 12-hour time, where HH is for 24-hour