# c# datetime.parseexact string was not recognized as a valid datetime

Tags: c#, datetime, culture, currentculture

Below code throws an exception on my local, but not on server.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("01/06/2015", "dd/MM/yyyy", null);
```

Like I said it works on the server, but it throws 'System.FormatException' on my local. I assume this might be a problem of Cultural settings. However I don't know where I can look into.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: You may probably want to look into this similar thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368636/why-cant-datetime-parseexact-parse-9-1-2009-using-m-d-yyyy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("01/06/2015", "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you don't specify the culture it will use whatever your current culture settings are. Since you know the format you should supply InvariantCulture.