# Calculate age from two dates vb.net

Tags: vb.net, date, datetime

I am trying to calculate age from dates. This works fine on the server computer but not on a particular client where it report error that "The string `07/21/2016` cannot be converted to a date". I found out that the locale of the server was set to `en-US` and the client with error locale is set to `en-UK`. I tried the code below to make the age calculation possible no matter the system locale but it has not worked.

```
Dim var as string = "07/30/2010"
Dim dob As String = Format(CDate(var & " 01:00:00"), "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
Dim dob1 As Date = DateTime.ParseExact(dob, "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
Dim todayDate As String = Format(Date.Now, "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss")
Dim todayDate1 As Date = DateTime.ParseExact(todayDate, "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
lblDob.Text = var & " (" & DateDiff(DateInterval.Year, dob1, todayDate1) - 1 & " yrs)"
```

Comment: Where do the dates come from? User input?

Comment: Dates are from the database entered via the server, the above date is just to illustrate.

Comment: and I assume (hope?) they're stored as `DateTime` in the database? Why bother with strings at all?

Comment: Yes, they are but in the format of `07/30/2010`. In the above code, I converted the string to date.

Comment: If they're stored as DateTime in the database, why bother with strings at all?

Comment: strings or not, they can be converted to date type

Comment: They can, of course, and you're on the right track with parse exact, you just need to know the format. The question is still valid though - why bother with strings at all?

Comment: And why the down-vote, please explain?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107457/discussion-between-christophano-and-diamond).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how I simplified your code and made it work:

```
    Dim userBirthDateText = "07/30/2010"
    Dim userBirthDate = Date.ParseExact(userBirthDateText.Replace("/", "-"), "MM-dd-yyyy", Nothing)
    Dim currentDate = Date.Now
    Dim age = Math.Floor(currentDate.Subtract(userBirthDate).TotalDays / 365)
```

Notice that I replace "/" by "-" in order to bypass the "slash problem" in dates (which is documented here: [Why can't DateTime.ParseExact() parse "9/1/2009" using "M/d/yyyy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368636/why-cant-datetime-parseexact-parse-9-1-2009-using-m-d-yyyy) ).

Also: I am simplifying the part about "how to get the timespan in years" (my simplification: just divide it by 365). If you want to make it more exact, it will need more work: [Format A TimeSpan With Years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15957984/format-a-timespan-with-years) .

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly and thanks again for the link.

Comment: It would be simpler to use `Dim userBirthDate = New DateTime(2010, 7, 30)`.

Answer (score 0):

I still had problems with time when using @XavierPena method but a all round method I used that worked in all cases is as follows;

```
'date can be in any form and this method worked for either US or UK locale
'this method always solve the problem of date settings e.g 9/24/2016 or 09/24/2016
Dim age as string = "07/30/2010"
'age
    Try
        Dim birthDate = Date.ParseExact(age.replace("/", "-"), "MM-dd-yyyy", Nothing)
        Return (Math.Floor(Date.Now.Subtract(birthDate).TotalDays / 365) & " yrs")

    Catch ex As Exception
        Try
            Dim birthDate = Date.ParseExact(age.replace("/", "-"), "M-dd-yyyy", Nothing)
            Return (Math.Floor(Date.Now.Subtract(birthDate).TotalDays / 365) & " yrs")
        Catch ex2 As Exception
            Try
                Dim birthDate = Date.ParseExact(age.replace("/", "-"), "M-d-yyyy", Nothing)
                Return (Math.Floor(Date.Now.Subtract(birthDate).TotalDays / 365) & " yrs")
            Catch ex3 As Exception
                Try
                    Dim birthDate = Date.ParseExact(age.replace("/", "-"), "MM-d-yyyy", Nothing)
                    Return (Math.Floor(Date.Now.Subtract(birthDate).TotalDays / 365) & " yrs")
                Catch ex4 As Exception
                    Try
                        Dim birthDate = Date.ParseExact(age.replace("/", "-"), "dd-MM-yyyy", Nothing)
                        Return (Math.Floor(Date.Now.Subtract(birthDate).TotalDays / 365) & " yrs")
                    Catch ex5 As Exception
                        Try
                            Dim birthDate = Date.ParseExact(age.replace("/", "-"), "dd-M-yyyy", Nothing)
                            Return (Math.Floor(Date.Now.Subtract(birthDate).TotalDays / 365) & " yrs")
                        Catch ex6 As Exception
                            Try
                                Dim birthDate = Date.ParseExact(age.replace("/", "-"), "d-M-yyyy", Nothing)
                                Return (Math.Floor(Date.Now.Subtract(birthDate).TotalDays / 365) & " yrs")
                            Catch ex7 As Exception
                                Dim birthDate = Date.ParseExact(age.replace("/", "-"), "d-MM-yyyy", Nothing)
                                Return (Math.Floor(Date.Now.Subtract(birthDate).TotalDays / 365) & " yrs")
                            End Try
                        End Try

                    End Try
                End Try
            End Try
        End Try

    End Try
```

Answer (score 0):

I use this code and it works for me.

```
Dim DoB as DateTime=dateTimePickerDoB.value.toshortdatestring
Dim DtNow as DateTime=Now.ToshortDatestring
Dim Age as Integer=Datediff(DateInterval.Year,DoB,DtNow)
txtage.text=age
```