# C# Validate the date before inserting them in to mysql

Tags: c#

I am working on getting the date validated before we insert them in to the mySQl server. Below is what I am trying

```
   DateTime startDate = new DateTime(2009, 12, 31);
   var currentTime = DateTime.Now;
   DateTime endDate = currentTime.Date;

   DateTime DOB = DateTime.ParseExact(emp[i].DateOfBirth, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,fff",                         System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

   if (!(DOB.Date > startDate && DOB.Date <= endDate))
   {
       WriteValidationFailure("Failed - DOB is Invalid");
   }
```

Here `emp[i].DateOfBirth` is a string and hold the value like `01/01/2009`. When I run the application it throws 
[image]

Comment: Your format expression does not match to your input data.

Comment: Try DateTime.Parse only with the datetime value, no format

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't DateTime.ParseExact() parse "9/1/2009" using "M/d/yyyy"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368636/why-cant-datetime-parseexact-parse-9-1-2009-using-m-d-yyyy)

Comment: Why don't you use **epoch time** to save into database :)

Comment: @HoangHieu, this question not about storing date in the DB, it's about wrong parsing before storing. Also epoch is not good choice if you need just write and read data to/from DB. Native date types is better choice for this case as does not require any conversions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use one of these statements to parse your date:

```
DateTime DOB = DateTime.ParseExact(emp[i].DateOfBirth, "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

or

```
DateTime DOB = DateTime.ParseExact(emp[i].DateOfBirth, "dd/MM/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

First if your dates contains month as first part and second for days as first part.