# String was not recognized as a valid DateTime error when compare two datetime variable

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

```
string date1="06/06/2017";
string date2="06/05/2017";
```

The dates are in format `mm/dd/yyyy`.I need to compare two dates

```
string test = DateTime.ParseExact(date1, "DD/M/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

I am unable to find out why I am getting error like String was not recognized as a valid `DateTime`.

Comment: If your dates are in "mm/dd/yyyy" why are you parsing as "DD/M/yyyy"?

Comment: go like this: var test = DateTime.ParseExact(date1, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

Comment: Be honest, Have you searched in google with the error message(*`String was not recognized as a valid DateTime`*

Comment: [please check this link it will be help you](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368636/why-cant-datetime-parseexact-parse-9-1-2009-using-m-d-yyyy)

Answer (score 4):

> The dates are in format `"mm/dd/yyyy"`

If dates are in this format use `"MM/dd/yyyy"` in `ParseExact()`:

```
var test = DateTime.ParseExact(date1, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Also, `ParseExact()` returns `DateTime`, not `string`. Use `var` or `DateTime`.

Comment: Important to note that it works only with `InvariantCulture`, otherwise the local date separater is used.

Comment: else if (DateTime.ParseExact(date1, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Date < DateTime.ParseExact(date2, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).Date && chk2.Checked == false)
                {
                    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "alert", "alert('Effective date from cannot be less than Effective To date !!!');", true); return;
                }             Its giving error

Comment: @priyathapliyal, you use `"dd/MM/yyyy"` when parse `date2`. Use `"MM/dd/yyyy"`

Comment: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Comment: @priyathapliyal, do you use same dates as in question?

Answer (score 1):

Use ToString() method like this
        `DateTime.ParseExact(date1,"MM/dd/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).ToString();`

this should solve your problem. problem is you cannot implicitly convert DateTime to string.

Comment: @priyathapliyal you have to convert the DateTime object to string. DateTime.ParseExact returns DateTime so you have to convert it to string using ToString()