# String to DateTime conversion not working

Tags: c#, datetime

I am converting one string to DateTime variable like this

```
 DateTime selecteddatetest = Convert.ToDateTime("09/21/2017");
```

This works fine in my production Server, But when I run this code in my local development machine, this throws an error

> System.FormatException: 'String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.'

Can anyone please point out what I am missing here?

Comment: You probably have a different culture between the machines, so the server is using the US format and your machine uses something else like UK. Obviously there is no month 21 in the UK. Specify the correct culture or use DateTime.ParseExact with the format you expect.

Comment: You are using a different locale on your production server and your local environment.

Comment: use DateTime.ParseExact https://stackoverflow.com/a/1368681/971839

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can't DateTime.ParseExact() parse "9/1/2009" using "M/d/yyyy"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368636/why-cant-datetime-parseexact-parse-9-1-2009-using-m-d-yyyy)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting a String to DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/919244/converting-a-string-to-datetime)

Comment: `Convert.ToDateTime("09/21/2017", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` otherwise your local date separator is used because `/` is a custom format specifier that says: please replace me with the actual date separator

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `ParseExact` if the time format is consistent:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("09/21/2017","MM/dd/yyyy", 
                     System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

Answer (score 3):

Its probably a localisation issue between the two machines, try specifying the date in the format "2017-09-21" and it should work everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

You are likely using a different culture between the two machines.

For example, the server is using the US culture which expects the format `MM/dd/yyyy` so your parsing works.
You local machine may be using a culture such as UK which expects the format `dd/MM/yyyy` and as there is no month 21 it fails.

You can specify the culture explicitly if you know it's always going to be the same:

```
Convert.ToDateTime("09/21/2017", new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
```

It may also work with an invariant culture:

```
Convert.ToDateTime("09/21/2017", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

You may also use `ParseExact` to specify the desired format:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("09/21/2017", "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```