# C# DateTime.ParseExact produces wrong dates

Tags: c#, date, datetime, asp.net-core

I'm trying to parse a date string in the form dd/mm/yyyy but I keep getting a consistent yet invalid results. What am I doing wrong?

here's the code and it's input

`DateTime.ParseExact("23/09/2018","d/m/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` =>
  1/**23**/18

`DateTime.ParseExact("8/10/2018","d/m/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` => 
 1/**8**/18

`DateTime.ParseExact("30/04/2018","d/m/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` =>
 1/**30**/18

I've tried using `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-UK")`, `CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-GH")` but still same results.

I've tried using "dd/mm/yyyy" still same results.

I've also tried qouting the slashed as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1368636/why-cant-datetime-parseexact-parse-9-1-2009-using-m-d-yyyy#1368681)   but still same results.

Comment: Use uppercase M for month. Lowercase is for minutes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
DateTime.ParseExact("23/09/2018","dd/MM/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
```

`MM/M` is used to parse months, `mm/m` is used for minutes.

Answer (score 4):

In C# 'M' is used for month and 'm' used for minute, [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings) you can find all details.

So please try:

```
   Console.WriteLine(DateTime.ParseExact("8/10/2018","d/M/yyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
```

for custom implementation you can visit [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#M_Specifier).

Answer (score 2):

Small 'm' stands for minutes, try 'M' or 'MM' for months